# Internationalization in JSF, when to use message-bundle and resource-bundle?

Tags: jsf, localization, internationalization

When and how should I use `<resource-bundle>` and `<message-bundle>` tags for localization in `faces-config.xml`? The differences between those two are not very clear to me.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

### <message-bundle>

The `<message-bundle>` is to be used whenever you want to override JSF default warning/error messages which is been used by the JSF validation/conversion stuff.
You can find keys of the default warning/error messages in chapter 2.5.2.4 of the [JSF specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jsf-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/jsf-2_0-fr-spec.pdf).

For example, `Messages_xx_XX.properties` files in `com.example.i18n` package as below which overrides the default `required="true"` message:

`com/example/i18n/Messages_en.properties`

```
javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED = {0}: This field is required
```

`com/example/i18n/Messages_nl.properties`

```
javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED = {0}: Dit veld is vereist
```

can be configured as follows (without the locale specifier `_xx_XX` and the file extension!):

```
<message-bundle>com.example.i18n.Messages</message-bundle>
```

---

### <resource-bundle>

The `<resource-bundle>` is to be used whenever you want to register a localized resource bundle which is available throughout the entire JSF application without the need to specify `<f:loadBundle>` in every single view.

For example, `Text_xx_XX.properties` files in `com.example.i18n` package as below:

`com/example/i18n/Text_en.properties`

```
main.title = Title of main page
main.head1 = Top heading of main page
main.form1.input1.label = Label of input1 of form1 of main page
```

`com/example/i18n/Text_nl.properties`

```
main.title = Titel van hoofd pagina
main.head1 = Bovenste kop van hoofd pagina
main.form1.input1.label = Label van input1 van form1 van hoofd pagina
```

can be configured as follows (without the locale specifier `_xx_XX` and the file extension!):

```
<resource-bundle>
    <base-name>com.example.i18n.Text</base-name>
    <var>text</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

and be used in `main.xhtml` as follows:

```
<h:head>
    <title>#{text['main.title']}</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1 id="head1">#{text['main.head1']}</h1>
    <h:form id="form1">
        <h:outputLabel for="input1" value="#{text['main.form1.input1.label']}" />
        <h:inputText id="input1" label="#{text['main.form1.input1.label']}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

---

### ValidationMessages (JSR303 Bean Validation)

Since Java EE 6 / JSF 2, there's also the new JSR303 Bean Validation API which is represented by those `@NotNull`, `Size`, `@Max`, etc annotations of the [`javax.validation.constraints`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html) package. You should understand that this API is **completely unrelated** to JSF. It is not part of JSF, but JSF just happens to have *support* for it during validations phase. I.e. it determines and recognizes the presence of a JSR303 implementation (e.g. Hibernate Validator) and then delegates the validation to it (which can be disabled by using `<f:validateBean disabled="true"/>`, by the way).

As per chapter 4.3.1.1 of the [JSR303 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/bean_validation-1.0-fr-oth-JSpec/bean_validation-1_0-final-spec.pdf), the custom JSR303 validation messages file needs to have **exactly** the name `ValidationMessages_xx_XX.properties` and it needs to be placed in the **root** of the classpath (thus, not in a package!).

---

### Localization

In the above examples, the `_xx_XX` in the filename represents the (optional) language and country codes. If this is absent altogether, then it becomes the default (fallback) bundle. If the language is present, e.g. `_en`, then it'll be used when the client has explicitly requested for this language in the [`Accept-Language`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) HTTP request header. The same applies to the country, e.g. `_en_US` or `_en_GB`.

You can specify the supported locales for both the message and resource bundle generically in `<locale-config>` element of `faces-config.xml`.

```
<locale-config>
    <default-locale>en</default-locale>
    <supported-locale>nl</supported-locale>
    <supported-locale>de</supported-locale>
    <supported-locale>es</supported-locale>
    <supported-locale>fr</supported-locale>
</locale-config>
```

The desired locale needs to be set via `<f:view locale>`. See also [Localization in JSF, how to remember selected locale per session instead of per request/view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830588).

Comment: Hello Balus C, can we use multiple <message-bundle> and how to call it from java bean?

Comment: Special care needs to be given to the folder structure when using the <resource-bundle>. If say you have the following in faces-config.xml <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>org.abc.def.messages</base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
        </resource-bundle>   then all message.properties, message_es.properties, message_de.properties should be in 'src/main/resources/org/abc/def folder' only. i.e. do not create a 'messages' folder under the 'def' folder. Till 'def' is what resource-bundle is expecting where it expects to find all messages_xx.properties files.