# What is the difference between message-bundle and resource-bundle in JSF

Tags: jsf, localization, internationalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSF - When to use message-bundle and resource-bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668161/jsf-when-to-use-message-bundle-and-resource-bundle)

HI,

I have started learning the concepts of displaying the messages in different languages. I come across two different elements in the Faces-config.xml. That is:

- message-bundle
- resource-bundle

What is the difference between these two elements.