# Can't find bundle for base name /Bundle, locale en_US

Tags: java, jsf

I'm using a library that has a dependency on JSF.

When I try to run my project, it show following exception massage..

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name /Bundle, locale en_US
at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1427)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1250)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:705)
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Looks like you're passing a wrong path.

Comment: You may try to check out this answer [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34731952/912829)

Comment: Create `Bundle.properties` file in your location: `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2668161/1599699

Comment: Try creating a resources folder on this path src/main/resources and then put or get your files from there by using ResourceBundle on Android.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44452218/1718223

Comment: Was getting this error when running intellij community version 2019.3. The solution was to downgrade.

Comment: I have to seriously advise to neither massage exceptions, nor pay attention when such is shown.

Answer (score 71):

The exception is telling that a `Bundle_en_US.properties`, or `Bundle_en.properties`, or at least `Bundle.properties` file is expected in the root of the classpath, but there is actually none.

Make sure that at least one of the mentioned files is present in the root of the classpath. Or, make sure that you provide the proper bundle name. For example, if the bundle files are actually been placed in the package `com.example.i18n`, then you need to pass `com.example.i18n.Bundle` as bundle name instead of `Bundle`.

In case you're using Eclipse "Dynamic Web Project", the classpath root is represented by `src` folder, there where all your Java packages are. In case you're using a Maven project, the classpath root for resource files is represented by `src/main/resources` folder.

#### See also:

- [Maven and JSF webapp structure, where exactly to put JSF resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540907/maven-and-jsf-webapp-structure-where-exactly-to-put-jsf-resources)

Comment: As also mentioned here, if you're on a Maven project manually create a new "resources" folder inside src/main/ and put all your resources inside it. Clean -> Build and run the project again resources will get picked up.

Answer (score 13):

### maven-tomcat-plugin

If you start the Project using the `maven-tomcat-plugin` / `maven-tomcat7-plugin`, you must place the `Bundle.properties`, or even the `Resource.properties` in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes`. Dont ask why, its because how the plugin fake a tomcat.

Comment: after move the .properties files into WEB-INF/classes (even create another wrapper folder under it) it works. up vote and thanks!

Comment: A quick thanks to Grim and lannyf, as their information helped me with a similar problem on Resin web server. I was working on a project where the properties file was stored along with the .jar files in `webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/`. There was nothing in `webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/`. When I tried copying this setup across to a new server, I got an error "Caught exception: Can't find base number for bundle X, locale en". However, when I created a symlink in `webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/` pointing to the .properties file in the `lib/` folder, it fixed the issue. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

If you are running the .java file in Eclipse you need to add the resource path in the build path . 
after that you will not see this error

Comment: Could you be more specifc?

Comment: Right click on project > Properties (alt + enter) > Java Builder Path > Source > Add Folder...

Answer (score 6):

In my case the problem was using the language tag "en_US" in `Locale.forLanguageTag(..)` instead of "en-US" - use a dash instead of underline!

Also use `Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US")` instead of `new Locale("en_US")` or `new Locale("en_US")` to define a language ("en") with a region ("US") - but `new Locale("en")` works.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problemo, and balus solution fixed it.

For the record:

WEB-INF\faces-config is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <message-bundle>
            Message
        </message-bundle>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

And had Message.properties under WebContent\Resources (after mkyong's tutorial)

the pesky exception appeared even when i renamed the bundle to "Message_en_us" and "Message_en". Moving it to src\ worked.

Should someone post the missing piece to make bundles work under resources,it would be a beautiful thing.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was dealing with **SpringBoot** project and I got the same exception.

Solution is made by **adding env.properties file into classpath** (i.e. src/main/resource folder). What was making the issue is that in log4j configuration there was property like

`<Property name="basePath">${bundle:env:log.file.path}</Property>`

Answer (score 1):

In maven, folder resources, create the same package structure where the configuration files are located and copy them there

Answer (score 1):

The `Bundle.properties` file must be in the directory of the `.class` files. If it is located in the `src` directory then you need to make sure to copy it to the `bin` (output) directory in the same package.

Answer (score 1):

Bundle names have to be fully qualified, like if your bundle **Bundle.properties**
is inside **x.y.z** package, then you have to write `ResourceBundle.getBundle("x.y.z.Bundle");`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Netbeans. I went to the project folder and copied the properties file. I think clicked "build" and then "classes."  I added the properties file in that folder. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use Eclipse (without Maven) so I place the `.properties` file in `src` folder that also contains the java source code, in order to have the `.properties` file in the `classes` folder after building the project. It works fine.
Take a look at this post: https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/cant-find-bundle-for-base-name-xxx-locale-en_us/

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be that the resource-bunde > base-name attribute at the **faces-config.xml** file has a different path to your properties. This happened to me on the firstcup Java EE tutorial, I gave a different package name on then project creation and then Glassfish was unable to find the properties folder which is on "firstcup.web".

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you didn't add the properties files in the wrong resources folder as there is one under 'Web Pages' and one under 'Other Sources/...'. They needed to be under 'Other Sources/...'.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue, the resource was in my project directories but when the junit utility tries to load it, it was returning an error of MissingResourceException. And the reason was the resource was in the not on the classpath of the test class package so when I added the cfg/ folder to my classpath path entry in eclipse and set the output directory in the build conf to the same class package the issue was resolved.

When you try this approach just make sure, the classpath conf file shows the classpath entry of the resource directory (eg. cfg/)