# java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name resources.application, locale en

Tags: jsf-2, resourcebundle, faces-config

My faces-config.xml likes below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web- 
facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<application>
    <message-bundle>resources.application</message-bundle>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>en</default-locale>
    </locale-config>
</application>

</faces-config>
```

Xhtml file

```
<f:loadBundle basename="resources.application" var="msg"/>
```

I am getting the below exception

```
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: //D:/12c_Workspace/VNPO/WebContent/login.xhtml @9,59 <f:loadBundle basename="resources.application"> Can't find bundle for base name resources.application, locale en
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.LoadBundleHandler.apply(LoadBundleHandler.java:233)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:774)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:338)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3288)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2163)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2089)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2074)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1513)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name resources.application, locale en
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1427)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1250)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:952)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.LoadBundleHandler.apply(LoadBundleHandler.java:227)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Exception clearly says that you don't have a `application_en.properties` or at least `application.properties` file in the `resources` package in the runtime classpath.

That's really it. Just make sure you have one.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I just want to warn that `<message-bundle>` and `<f:loadBundle>` are mutually exclusive. To learn about the difference, head to [Internationalization in JSF, when to use message-bundle and resource-bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668161/when-to-use-message-bundle-and-resource-bundle/)

Comment: Hi. I have "application.properties" file at "resources" folder.

Comment: *Package*, not folder. A "folder" has no special meaning in Java while a "package" is a folder which actually ends up in runtime classpath (and usually contains Java classes, but can also contain properties files and such). It sounds like you got classpath/building/packaging concepts and/or project structure messed up. First of all, are you using Maven or so?

Comment: I am not using Maven, Sorry that was package like src/resources

Comment: Well, apparently build went wrong. Either the build skipped `.properties` files, or the build hasn't run at all. Check build settings, clean, rebuild, redeploy, etc. To exclude one and other, let the build export a WAR file and then unzip it yourself to see if `/WEB-INF/classes/resources/application.properties` file is physically present. If not, then that totally explains the exception.

Comment: thanks Buddy. now it is got resolved    . but I am getting one more issue while pointing the value from properties files.

Answer (score 4):

You need 2 things:

1. To have your `messages.properties` file in your class-path. The safest bet is to put it under `src/main/java/your/package/name`
2. Configure it in your `faces-config.xml`:

http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
        version="2.2">

```
    <application>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>your.package.name.messages</base-name>
            <var>i18n</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>

</faces-config>
```

Note that you don't include `.properties` suffix in `faces-config.xml`

Comment: Thing 1 is already answered. Thing 2 is already done by OP. How exactly does this post answer OP's concrete problem and/or add up to what's already mentioned/given?

Comment: My answer relates to the case when packages are being used (good practice). In his example he didn't specify it with package name in faces-config.xml Also you are suggesting to put in src/main/resources. I am suggesting to put in src/main/java

Comment: OP used package `resources` in src.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Maven you must to put the properties files in the folder src/main/resources not with the packages thar are in src/main/java

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

- **Step I :** Keep Maven files to install and use.
- **Step II:** You need to set class path of Maven in Environment Variable
- **Step III:** Install Maven with command `mvn install` on **command prompt** after reaching then `/bin` directory in Maven directory.

**Now clean project and deploy Maven Project to run.**

Answer (score -1):

With Eclipse and Windows: you have to copy 2 files

- xxxPROJECTxxx.properties
- log4j.properties

here :
   C:\Eclipse\CONTENER\TOMCAT\apache-tomcat-7\lib