# Maven doesn't include properties bundle file in ear

Tags: java, maven, netbeans-7

I've created a properties file to externalize my JSF pages. Its location is a source package in the web application:

[image]

I've included it in the faces-config.xml file with the full path:

```
<application>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>en</default-locale>
    </locale-config>

    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>com.daslernen.bundles.messages</base-name>
        <var>bundle</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>
```

But if I explore the contents of the war file inside the ear file as suggested in [this answer to the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20328691) I don't find not the package neither the properties file.

How can I make Maven to include it in the build?

PS: If it helps I'm using Netbeans and a Maven project created with the wizard.

Comment: Where are these properties located in the folder structure ?

Comment: @khmarbaise: In the source package of the project. Classes in the the parent package are already being built and run in Glassfish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the properties files being in the source directory, Maven was building it a different one called main.java.the_path_where_the_file_really_is. For the moment and while I try to figure out how to make Maven place the file in the correct place I have modified the faces-config.xml file to include the path Maven left the file:

```
main.java.com.daslernen.bundles.messages
```

And now works like a charm :)