# ResourceBundle on Android in Assets folder

Tags: android, assets, resourcebundle

i´m currently useing ResourceBundles in a pure Java program. Now I want to use the same files inside of an Android app. It works as intended, when the file is placed e.g. at /sdcard/. Is there a way to load them directly from the known android folder structure? e.g. from assets wihtout manually coping them to the sdcard?

This works at the sdcard:

```
    File file = new File("/sdcard/");
    URL[] urls = new URL[0];
    try {
       urls = new URL[]{file.toURI().toURL()};

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
    ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("test", Locale.DEFAULT, loader);
```

This url doesn´t work for the assests folder:

```
   urls = new URL[]{new URL("file:///android_asset/test/")};
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: if you want a way to load file from assets, take a look at this answer


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9544781/4224337

Comment: @Rami ResourceBunlde can´t handle an InputStream

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a `resources` folder on this path `src/main/resources` and then put or get your files from there by using `ResourceBundle` on Android.

It works for me.