# Can't find bundle for base name that doesn't solve with similar questions

Tags: java, localization

I should design a localized App,But finally this error returns :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name messages, locale fa
```

Piece of code:

```
 ResourceBundle bundle =
            ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages",new Locale("fa"));
```

and image from my project structure(I tested it jsp page with similar error  now I'm testing in a class with main method (TestCalender.java)) :

[image]

---

### EDIT:

I saw similar questions and test their answers but no changes detected in my error!

Comment: According to an answer on a similar question, it's looking for the bundle at the root of the classpath and that isn't where the bundle is located.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't find bundle for base name /Bundle, locale en\_US](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986234/cant-find-bundle-for-base-name-bundle-locale-en-us)

Comment: Unlike.Nope!I put the bundles in several places also root of calsspatp but No Change!!!

Comment: I solve that by copy bundles to target dir!!!!
I don't know why they doesn't copied here automatic !!

@BSMP Do yo know ?

Comment: I don't know why that isn't automatic but you can add that as the answer to the question so others can see that there's a solution.

Comment: Sure,I add answer after finding best solution ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that :

Because of I'm using Maven and Some configs should add to `pom.xml` file for adding resources to `target` dir.

Here's what I did:

```
     <plugins>
        <!--Some plugins omitted >
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include> **/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include> **/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Comment: T.V.B &#x1f495;