# Override Primefaces Messages in custom properties file

Tags: jsf, primefaces, internationalization

I want to override some PrimeFaces defaults.

According to this link [PrimeFaces default messages.properties](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/primefaces/Messages.properties) I wrote a custom message properties:

```
primefaces.captcha.INVALID = {0}: Erro de Valida\u00e7\u00e3o: Valor inv\u00e1lido.
primefaces.captcha.INVALID_detail = {0}: ''{1}'' n\u00e3o confere com o texto exibido.
primefaces.password.INVALID_MATCH = {0}: Erro de Valida\u00e7\u00e3o: Valor inv\u00e1lido.
primefaces.password.INVALID_MATCH_detail = {0} deve ser igual a {1}.
```

How can I override some features like weekLabel, goodLabel, strongLabel in the password for example?

I'd like to know what properties keys I should use.

Comment: Have you tried searching on the PrimeFaces Documentation?

Comment: Yes. All I found is [link](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.5/)

Comment: What about [PF 3.5 User Guide](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/indexed_primefaces_users_guide_3_5.pdf)?

Comment: I've searched there also. The only thing it states is that we can provide custom labels like:
<p:password value="#{bean.password}" promptLabel="Lütfen şifre giriniz"
weakLabel="Zayıf" goodLabel="Orta seviye" strongLabel="Güçlü" feedback= "true"/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those labels are not part of conversion/validation messages. Those labels are part of pure text presentation. You need to supply them yourself via [standard JSF resource bundle mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668161/when-to-use-message-bundle-and-resource-bundle/2668602#2668602).

E.g. `com.example.i18n.text.properties`:

```
primefaces.password.weakLabel = Zayıf
primefaces.password.goodLabel = Orta seviye
primefaces.password.strongLabel = Güçlü
```

which is configured in `faces-config.xml` as follows:

```xml
<resource-bundle>
    <base-name>com.example.i18n.text</base-name>
    <var>text</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

and used in the view as follows:

```
weakLabel="#{text['primefaces.password.weakLabel']}"
goodLabel="#{text['primefaces.password.goodLabel']}"
strongLabel="#{text['primefaces.password.strongLabel']}"
```

Comment: I already did that, but I'm trying to avoid that using something **automatic**.