# java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle

Tags: java, jsf

I've searched but to no avail. I'm getting this error in my console when running my JSF application.

I'm trying to add a basic messages.properties file to my calculator app, working from a tutorial. The tutorial says to "If you are using Eclipse Java EE, be sure to add resources/messages.properties as a source folder."

Is this in the build path of the application? because I've tried that and it doesn't work.

File path of my properties file: ProjectName/WebContent/resources/messages.properties

How I reference the properties file in my faces-config.xml:

```
<application>
<message-bundle>/JavaServerFaces/WebContent/resources/messages</message-bundle>
</application>
```

Filepath of my faces-config.xml: ProjectName/WebContent/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668161/when-to-use-message-bundle-and-resource-bundle

Answer (score 2):

The bundle file has to end up in the classpath and needs to be identified as a classpath resource, not as a local disk file system path nor a web resource.

- Create a package `resources` the in the same place and the same way as you would create a package for your Java code.
- Drop the `messages.properties` file in there.
- Reference it as `<message-bundle>resources.messages</message-bundle>`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That certainly helps, my application doesn't 404 any more when I make a calculation. However it doesn't load the messages in the file either.. Any idea what might be causing that?

Comment: Also there isn't any consol output to hint towards what the error is either

Comment: How exactly did you conclude that it doesn't load the messages? Are you sure that you aren't confusing resource bundle with message bundle like as many starters? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668161/when-to-use-message-bundle-and-resource-bundle/

Comment: Because the messages I'm putting in the resources file aren't showing. I'm not 100% sure on the difference between the two, but I'm following this tutorial http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jsf1/section4.html which is using messagebundle so I assume it's correct.