# JSF <h:message /> inside <h:graphicImage /> title

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2

So, I am trying to display validation error messages as image title. I want to do that, because messages are quite long and I don't want them to take place on my page.

Tried to bind UIComponent `<h:message />` object to controller object, but then I couldn't find out how to get a span's value from UIComponent.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just control the markup yourselves inside an `<ui:repeat>` while iterating over the messages. You can obtain messages in EL by [`FacesContext#getMessageList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getMessageList%28%29).

So instead of,

```
<h:inputText id="foo" ... />
<h:message for="foo" />
```

do something like

```
<h:inputText binding="#{foo}" ... />
<ui:repeat value="#{facesContext.getMessageList(foo.clientId)}" var="message">
    <h:graphicImage name="#{message.severity}.png" title="#{message.summary}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

where the `#{message}` is an instance of [`FacesMessage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/FacesMessage.html), offering the usual getters.

Comment: Thx for the answer, didn't know about `facesContext.getMessageList` thx!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to define and put all these long messages in `.properties`'s file, as bundle messages. Take a look here : [When to use message bundle and resource bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668161/when-to-use-message-bundle-and-resource-bundle)

Comment: Thx for the reply, and yes, I know that I can override these messages. Still, do you think that the only possible solution is to make these messages shorter and there is no way to put them as image's title?

Comment: Maybe it's possible, but it gonna be more complicated (more code in the backing-beans).

Comment: Not a problem actuallly. The only thing I need, is to find out how to get `<span>Validation message</span>` validation message from UIComponent. Probably I will leave it for now, unless someone will give me a hint.