# How to sort a list that will be localized in JSF output

Tags: sorting, jsf, localization, resourcebundle

In my application I have a list of keys (strings), where the user can select one of them. In the user-interface, the keys will be output according to the current locale:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedKey}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{bean.allKeys}" var="_key" itemLabel="#{msgs[_key]}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

My setup uses a standard resource-bundle configured in `faces-config.xml` as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668161/when-to-use-message-bundle-and-resource-bundle#2668602) by BalusC. `msgs` in the example above is the name of the resource-bundle variable.

What I want now, is the items from the `selectOneMenu` to be sorted in alphabetic order. Of course the order depends on the used locale. The problem is, I can't/won't do the sorting in the backing-bean, as I don't know how the JSF-page will output the keys.

This problem seems quite generic to me, so I'm wondering what the best practice is to solve this kind of problem.

(Of course the problem is not only applicable to `selectOneMenu`. Any list/collection that will be output in the user-interface suffers from the same problem.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've basically 2 options.

1. Sort in client side with a little help of JS. I'll for simplicity assume that you're using jQuery.

   ```
   <h:selectOneMenu ... styleClass="ordered">
   ```

   ```js
   $("select.ordered").each(function(index, select) {
       var $select = $(select);
       $select.find("option").sort(function(left, right) {
           return left.text == right.text ? 0 : left.text < right.text ? -1 : 1;
       }).appendTo($select);
       if (!$select.find("option[selected]").length) {
           select.options.selectedIndex = 0;
       }
   });
   ```

   ---
2. Sort in server side wherein you create `List<SelectItem>` and grab `#{msgs}` via injection. Assuming that you're using CDI and thus can't use `@ManagedProperty("#{msgs}")`, you'd need to create a producer for that first. I'll for simplicity assume that you're using OmniFaces (which is also confirmed based on your question history).

   ```
   public class BundleProducer {

       @Produces
       public PropertyResourceBundle getBundle() {
           return Faces.evaluateExpressionGet("#{msgs}");
       }

   }
   ```

   Then you can make use of it as follows in the backing bean associated with `<f:selectItems value>`:

   ```
   private static final Comparator<SelectItem> SORT_SELECTITEM_BY_LABEL = new Comparator<SelectItem>() {
       @Override
       public int compare(SelectItem left, SelectItem right) {
           return left.getLabel().compareTo(right.getLabel());
       }
   };

   private List<SelectItem> allKeys;

   @Inject
   private PropertyResourceBundle msgs;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
       allKeys = new ArrayList<>();

       for (String key : keys) {
          allKeys.add(new SelectItem(key, msgs.getString(key)));
       }

       Collections.sort(allKeys, SORT_SELECTITEM_BY_LABEL);
   }
   ```

   And reference it directly without `var` as follows:

   ```
   <f:selectItems value="#{bean.allKeys}" />
   ```

Comment: Thanks @BalusC, all your assumptions were correct :)
Especially option one (the JavaScript solution) is new to me and I'll have a closer look. As always, very good and detailed explanations!

Comment: The injection doesn't work if the bean is ViewScoped : serialization problem.

Comment: Resource bundles are indeed request scoped. You can safely use a different bean for `<f:selectItems value>` than for `<h:selectOneMenu value>`.