# Where to store static locale specific properties

Tags: jsf

What is the correct scope to store static locale specific properties in?

I am thinking about either storing it in the session or application scope to prevent loading the same static properties over and over again.

Comment: What exactly are "static locale specific properties"? i18n/l10n bundles? For text content? If so, why not just making use of JSF builtin resource management facility?

Comment: You should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668161/when-to-use-message-bundle-and-resource-bundle/2668602#2668602)