# In what context is "msg" a reserved keyword?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

The following dataTable shows "???messageId???" instead of the correct id:

```
<p:dataTable id="msgTable" var="msg" value="#{msgModel.messages}">
        <p:column headerText="Id">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg.messageId}" />
        </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

After some tedious debugging, I found that it worked **when renaming the var to something else than "msg"**

```
<p:dataTable id="msgTable" var="msg2" value="#{msgModel.messages}">
        <p:column headerText="Id">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg2.messageId}" />
        </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

**In what context is "msg" a reserved keyword ?** I could not find any documentation about it for html, Javascript or JSF ?

Comment: Is `msg` defined in your `faces-config.xml`?

Comment: That was it. Another developer put it there without my knowing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a reserved keyword.

The name "msg" is however recognizable as the value of `<resource-bundle><var>` as seen in `faces-config.xml` of many JSF tutorials and kickoff applications.

```
<resource-bundle>
    ...
    <var>msg</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

The error message which you got also confirms it. When a resource bundle message is not found by given key, by default the very same key is returned surrounded with three quesiton marks, exactly as you've observed:

> ???key???

#### See also:

- [Internationalization in JSF, when to use message-bundle and resource-bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668161/internationalization-in-jsf-when-to-use-message-bundle-and-resource-bundle)