# Custom JSF f:validateLenght message without using @FacesValidator class

Tags: validation, jsf

In this example

```
<h:inputSecret value="#{contact.password}">
            <f:validator validatorId="passwordValidator"/>
            <f:validateLength minimum="8"/>
</h:inputSecret><br/>
```

If i put a password shorter than 8 letters i have **j_idt10: Validation Error: Length is less than allowable minimum of '8'** which is exactly what i want but i would like to rewrite the error message. I can do it using a custom **@FacesValidator** and i checked if there are some attribute in **f:validateLength** to do this but i didn't find any. Is writing a FacesValidator the only solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `message-bundle` (similar but **not** same as resource-bundle) to override default conversion and validation messages:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2668602/1072089