# Primefaces Calendar don't show seconds

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a calendar where I can pick the date and time (only hours and minutes):

`<p:calendar locale="de" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"`

No I have to provide english translations as well. So I need to remove the `locale` and `pattern` part.

Is there a possiblility to have a locale aware calendar with date and time (no seconds) ?

Summary:
When locale is German, I want to have `dd.mm.yyyy HH:mm`. When the locale is English, I want to have `mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm`

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668161/internationalization-in-jsf-when-to-use-message-bundle-and-resource-bundle

Comment: did you try `dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss` ?!?

Comment: well then it is english by default. I want `dd.mm.yyyy HH:mm` for German and `mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm` for English

Comment: Use a resource bundle to create a pattern per locale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hook the pattern attribute up to a bean method which returns the pattern you want for each given locale.

```
<p:calendar pattern="#{bean.localePattern}">

public String getLocalePattern() {
    Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
    if (Locale.GERMAN.equals(locale)) {
        return "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm";
    } else if (Locale.ENGLISH.equals(locale)) {
        return "MM/dd/yyy HH:mm";
    }else {
        //return default pattern...
    }
}
```

Edit: Jaspers suggestion to take advantage of a localized resource bundle is a great one (if you're already/plan to use JSF's built in localization features).

Comment: removing `:ss` from the pattern seems to be more dynamic to me. However, note that the month is represented by `M` (uppercase)