# How to specify a UTF-8 character in JSF XHTML?

Tags: string, jsf, utf-8

In Java using UTF-8 characters in a `String` is as easy as specifiying `"\u2022"`. Afaik strings specified in the JSF expression language are Java strings, e.g. `#{'some string'}` (where `''` is used to delimit the string because `""` is already used to delimit XHTML attribute values).

How can I specify the above string `"\u2022"` in JSF XHTML, e.g. in the `value` of a `h:outputLabel`?

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{'\u2022'}"/>
```

fails due to `/index.xhtml @9,45 value="#{'\u2022'}" Error Parsing: #{'\u2022'}`.

```
<h:outputLabel value="\u2022"/>
```

results in `u2022` being generated in XHTML.

The search for information is difficult because encoding on web pages is very important and the search results are dominated by explanations of it.

Referencing a `String` property in a backing bean is a valid workaround as well as using a resource bundle.

Comment: http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for your input. I tried that unsuccessfully (edited). The link to balusc's blog is valuable, but mostly covers encoding issues which are not the main problem here (more of a syntax issue), do you have a specific passage in the blog post in mind?

Comment: Maybe I miss what you effectively want to achieve (looking at the other answer).  Your remarks about the ' are somewhat confusing

Comment: @Kukeltje In Java you can specify a UTF-8 character as `String` or `char` (delimited with `""` and `''` respectively). In JSF I can't declare a `char` because `''` is used to delimit string because `""` is already used to delimit XHTML attributes and thus using `""` inside an attribute with is already delimited with `""` would cause unnecessary compiler challanges and make the code harder to read than necessary. I just wanted to avoid comments and answers explaining that. I'll remove it.

Comment: @Kukeltje I want to know the syntax to declare a UTF-8 character, e.g. 2022, in XHTML or an explanation why this isn't possible.

Comment: In the BalusC blog he talks about how the file is **locally** saved, e.g. in your IDE. Check those things. I don't see any other reason that the thing in my first comment should not work (or give you what you experience and not another weird character)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usual JSF value attribute refers to a backing bean object which often delivers a `String`. This string supports HTML UTF-8 escaping like this `&#xAAAA;` where `AAAA` is the hexadecimal code of the unicode character.

So, simply write this :

```
<h:outputLabel value="&#x2022;" />
```

You can write this escape sequence in an Expression Language litteral as well :

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{'&#x2022;'}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

XHTML is a XML markup language, and as such accepts escaping to xml entities:

```
<h:outputText value="&quot;User&quot;" />
```

will print

```
"User"
```

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML

You could also use a resource bundle, which will provide you with multilingal support and unicode encoding. Then you could use:

```
<h:outputText  value="#{msg.user}"/>
```

And in the messages.properties file:

```
user=\u2022User\u2022
```

See BalusC answer: [Internationalization in JSF, when to use message-bundle and resource-bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668161/internationalization-in-jsf-when-to-use-message-bundle-and-resource-bundle)

Comment: Thanks for you input. However I don't see how XML escaping is related to my question, please explain. Specifying the character in a resource bundle seems more complex than specifying it as a literal in a backing bean. It's another workaround.